# help on getting image src from a table cell using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have a html page that has a form, and a table inside the form that has rows of products.

I got to the point now where I am looping through the table rows, and in each loop I grab all the table cells.

```
for tr in t.findAll('tr'):
    td = tr.findAll('td')
```

Now I want to grab the image src url from the first td.

Html looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td ...>
    <a href ... >
       <img ... src="asdf/asdf.jpg" .. >
    </a>
  </td>

  ...
</tr>
```

How would I go about doing this?  I keep thinking in terms of regex.

I tried:

`td[0].a.image.src` but that didn't work as it says no attribute 'src'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
td[0].a.img['src']
```

I imagine your use of `image` for `img` in the question was just a transcription error, but the important point is that, in BeautifulSoup, in order to access a tag's HTML attributes you use indexing notation (like the `['src']` in my code snippet above), not dot-syntax -- the dot-syntax notation actually proceeds down the tree instead (just as it's doing above for the two dots, one each just before `a` and `img`).